# How to get mesuaredWidth of ListView

Tags: android, listview, layout

I have a ListView myList, and several items in it. I've set myList width to fill_parent, and parent is Fragment. Then I set up width of my Fragment to 100, and the width of myList is 100 too (getWidth() method). But item text in myList is cutted, and it is ok. All I need is to know for what size I should set width of my Fragment to match size of text in myList.

I thought that measuredWidth() of myList should return this value, but it returns the same as getWidht(), what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for helping